# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such accessible method: matcherForSufficientlyVisible() on class: com.wix.detox.espresso.DetoxMatcher

Tags: android, react-native, detox

I'm trying to call toBeVisible() from Detox which is documented here:

https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/api/expect#tobevisible

But every time I try to run a code such as:

```
await expect(element(by.id('UniqueId203'))).toBeVisible();
```

It's throwing an exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such accessible method: matcherForSufficientlyVisible() on class: com.wix.detox.espresso.DetoxMatcher
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.MethodUtils.invokeStaticMethod(MethodUtils.java:439)
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.MethodUtils.invokeStaticMethod(MethodUtils.java:405)
        at com.wix.invoke.types.ClassTarget.execute(ClassTarget.java:23)
        at com.wix.invoke.types.Target.invoke(Target.java:59)
        at com.wix.invoke.types.Target.invoke(Target.java:55)
        at com.wix.invoke.MethodInvocation.invoke(MethodInvocation.java:35)
        at com.wix.invoke.MethodInvocation.invoke(MethodInvocation.java:26)
        at com.wix.invoke.MethodInvocation.invoke(MethodInvocation.java:20)
        at com.wix.detox.adapters.server.InvokeActionHandler.handle(DetoxActionHandlers.kt:56)
        at com.wix.detox.adapters.server.ActionsExecutor$executeAction$$inlined$let$lambda$1.run(DetoxActionsDispatcher.kt:64)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at com.wix.detox.adapters.server.ActionsExecutor$1.run(DetoxActionsDispatcher.kt:50)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

All the rest of Detox functions such as `detox.init()` and finding and clicking on elements are behaving as expected. But for some reason `toBeVisible()` is throwing an exception. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/2483#issuecomment-733931151

This might be because on your machine the JS and Native sides of Detox have gone out of sync.

Best if you just run this inside your app's android (native) directory:

```
./gradlew clean
```

And then build as you normally would

```
detox build -c ...
```